# Dynamically Create Sort Lambda Expression

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, dynamic, lambda

I want to use a lambda expression to sort an IEnumerable of an arbitrary entity type by an arbitrary column / field name.

I have this sort function:

```
 public static IEnumerable<T> SortByFieldName<T>(IEnumerable<T> target, string sortPropertyName, string sortDirection)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortPropertyName))
        {
            Expression<Func<T, object>> sortExpression = GetSortLambda<T>(sortPropertyName);
            switch (sortDirection.ToLower())
            {
                case "a":
                    return target.AsQueryable<T>().OrderBy(sortExpression);
                case "d":
                    return target.AsQueryable<T>().OrderByDescending(sortExpression);
                default:
                    return target;
            }
        }
        return target;
    }
```

with this function to create the expression (modified from another answer here)

```
        public static Expression<Func<T,object>> GetSortLambda<T>(string propertyPath)
    {
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "p");
        var parts = propertyPath.Split('.');
        Expression parent = param;
        foreach (var part in parts)
        {
            parent = Expression.Property(parent, part);
        }

        var sortExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(parent, param);
        return sortExpression;
    }
```

This works as expected for any property path that resolves to a string, but for Integers (and less frequently for Boolean) the following error is generated (in the case Int32 property):

> Expression of type 'System.Int32' cannot be used for return type 'System.Object'

This is, I think, because the expression being returned as

```
Expression<Func<T,object>>
```

but I can't figure out how to overcome this - `object` ought to cover all property types, shouldn't it?

I probably can do this with reflection, getting the PropertyInfo (and thereby type) for the target column but I always choose to avoid reflection if possible.

Any guidance / suggestions appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might need to [`Convert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb292051(v=vs.110).aspx) the expression if you are dealing with value types such as integers or dates:

```
public static Expression<Func<T, object>> GetSortLambda<T>(string propertyPath)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "p");
    var parts = propertyPath.Split('.');
    Expression parent = param;
    foreach (var part in parts)
    {
        parent = Expression.Property(parent, part);
    }

    if (parent.Type.IsValueType)
    {
        var converted = Expression.Convert(parent, typeof(object));
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(converted, param);
    }
    else
    {
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(parent, param);
    }
}
```